# Move constraints of UILabels when swiping a UITableViewCell to the right

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints, uitableview, swipe-gesture

I have a custom UITableViewCell composed by two detail labels located at the beginning of the cell (one above the other) a thin view (used as a separator which the labels have their constraints related to), the main label and a button.

[image]

I implemented an animation to "hide" (actually moving to a non-visible position) the detail labels after some time when the tableview is loaded.

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {

        self.tableView.visibleCells.forEach { (cell) in
            let songCell = cell as! SongCell
            songCell.layoutIfNeeded()
            songCell.leadingHoursSeparatorConstraint.constant = -10
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.33) {
                songCell.layoutIfNeeded()
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to be able to see the detail labels when swiping the cell to the right. Any suggestions on how to achieve this? Any help will be appreciated :D

Comment: In this code, you just move leading space didn't hide anything.

Comment: @user3589771 yeah, sorry I expressed it wrong.

Comment: [There is few 3rd lib](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=tableview+cell+swipe&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&ei=-95LWcKeLYvy8AfFjpiQBg) available for that if you want.
You should update your `UILabel` superview when change leading. Other than `UILabel` should be like `bringSubViewToFront`